# Как из массива чисел удалить все повторяющиеся и оставить уникальное число?

Tags: javascript

Пример: ***findUniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]) => 2***

Я первым делом сортирую числа и таким образом делаю их парами.

Следующим шагом я прохожусь по массиву, вырезаю эти пары и помещаю в result. На следующей итерации они заменяются следующей вырезаной парой

Последний шаг, когда нету с чем сравнивать число, я рассчитываю, что первая инструкция if не выполнится и перейдет к следующей. И уже в следующей инструкции число по индексу будет равно длине массива и это число последним перезапишет  result.

Проблема в том, что последняя инструкция не выполняется.

```
    function findUniq(arr) {
  let myArray = arr.sort((a,b)=> a-b)
    //expected result [0, 0, 1, 1, 3]
  let result = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
        if (myArray[i] == myArray[1]){
            result = myArray.splice(0,2)
            // инструкция для случая когда в массиве остается одно
            // число без пары, которое надо вернуть
        } else if (myArray.length == myArray[i+1]){
            result = myArray[i]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете побитовую операцию xor?

Answer (score 2):

Для случая, когда повторов чётное количество (вы упоминаете пары)

```js
function findUniq(arr) {
   let res = 0;
   for (let x of arr) 
      res ^= x;
   return res
}

console.log(findUniq([1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]))
```

Comment: Но даже в примере повторов нечетное количество)

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar Да, я заметил, но не факт, что так и должно быть, точное условие ведь не приведено. Я предположил, что автор стал попарно удалять именно потому, что должно быть всего по парам, кроме одного числа.

Answer (score 0):

используйте Set

https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-create-an-array-of-unique-values-in-javascript-using-sets-5dg6

```
const cars = ['Volvo', 'Jeep', 'Volvo', 'Lincoln', 'Lincoln', 'Ford'];
const uniqueCars = Array.from(new Set(cars));
console.log(uniqueCars);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: возвращает ['Volvo', 'Jeep', 'Lincoln', 'Ford']. задача немного другая: удалить повторяющиеся числа и оставить уникальное число Пример: findUniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]) => 2

Comment: тогда в хэш и подсчитывать в аккумуляторах количество уникальных и удалять с числом в аккумуляторе более 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7];

const unique = [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(unique)
```

**Source:** https://learn.javascript.ru/map-set#set

Comment: возвращает [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]. задача немного другая: удалить повторяющиеся числа и оставить уникальное число

Пример: findUniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]) => 2

Answer (score 0):

Я бы это решил так.
По элементам проходим и считаем количество повторов, запиываем в массив. По массиву проходим и смотрим, чего больше одного, фильтруем. Получаем в результате только элементы без повторов.

```js
let data = [0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

function findUniq(data) {
  let count = [];

  data.forEach((val) => {
    if (count[val] != undefined) {
      ++count[val]
    } else {
      count[val] = 1
    }
  })

  count.forEach((count, val) => {
    if (count > 1) {
      data = data.filter(el => el !== val)
    }
  })

  return data
}

console.log(findUniq(data))
```